# MudBlazor Component Sizing & Layout

Tags: c#, blazor, mudblazor

In the example code on Mudblazor's website (https://mudblazor.com/components/select#variants) there is no sizing or layout specified, they just line up neatly next to each other. When I implement the code it makes the select boxes 100% of the page width and places them on top of each other instead of next to each other. How would you go about setting the size and layout/placement of the components? I would like the two select boxes side by side and the checkbox and buttons centered.

[image]

```
    <MudSelect T="MailboxUser" Placeholder="Select Forward From Mailbox" Variant="Variant.Outlined" Label="Forward From" @bind-Value="@SelectedForwardFrom" AnchorOrigin="Origin.BottomCenter" Dense="true" FullWidth="false">
        @foreach (var user in SortedUsers)
        {
            <MudSelectItem Value="@user" >@user.DisplayName (@user.PrimarySmtpAddress)</MudSelectItem>
        }
    </MudSelect>

    <MudSelect T="MailboxUser" Placeholder="Select Forward To Mailbox" Variant="Variant.Outlined" Label="Forward To" @bind-Value="@SelectedForwardTo" AnchorOrigin="Origin.BottomCenter" Dense="true" FullWidth="false">
        @foreach (var user in SortedUsers)
        {
            <MudSelectItem Value="@user">@user.DisplayName (@user.PrimarySmtpAddress)</MudSelectItem>
        }
    </MudSelect>
    <MudCheckBox @bind-Checked="@SendToBoth" Color="Color.Primary" Label="Deliver To Both Mailboxes"></MudCheckBox>
    <MudButton Variant="Variant.Filled" Color="Color.Primary" @onclick="HandleSetForwardAction">Set Forward</MudButton>
    <MudButton Variant="Variant.Filled" Color="Color.Primary" @onclick="HandleRefreshAction">Refresh</MudButton>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a grid for your form inputs.

In MudBlazor this is the MudGrid.  I don't have MudBlazor installed on my travelling machine, so here's some example code I lifted straight from here - https://www.mudblazor.com/components/autocomplete#usage.

The `xs`, `sm`,... control the formatting at different screen widths so you can collapse a row into columns on small screens.  You'll need to read up on that.

```cs
<MudGrid>
    <MudItem xs="12" sm="6" md="4">
        <MudAutocomplete T="string" Label="US States" @bind-Value="value1" SearchFunc="@Search1"
                         ResetValueOnEmptyText="@resetValueOnEmptyText"
                         CoerceText="@coerceText" CoerceValue="@coerceValue" />
    </MudItem>
    <MudItem xs="12" sm="6" md="4">
        <MudAutocomplete T="string" Label="US States" @bind-Value="value2" SearchFunc="@Search2"
                         ResetValueOnEmptyText="@resetValueOnEmptyText"
                         CoerceText="@coerceText" CoerceValue="@coerceValue"
                         AdornmentIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Search" AdornmentColor="Color.Primary" />
    </MudItem>
    <MudItem xs="12" md="12">
        <MudText Class="mb-n3" Typo="Typo.body2">
            <MudChip>@(value1 ?? "Not selected")</MudChip><MudChip>@(value2 ?? "Not selected")</MudChip>
        </MudText>
    </MudItem>
    <MudItem xs="12" md="12" class="flex-column">
        <MudSwitch @bind-Checked="resetValueOnEmptyText" Color="Color.Primary">Reset Value on empty Text</MudSwitch>
        <MudSwitch @bind-Checked="coerceText" Color="Color.Secondary">Coerce Text to Value</MudSwitch>
        <MudSwitch @bind-Checked="coerceValue" Color="Color.Tertiary">Coerce Value to Text (if not found)</MudSwitch>
    </MudItem>
</MudGrid>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, however I am still missing how to center an item in the grid. I don't know why I can't seem to find this in the documentation. I will keep looking. On a side note I was looking all over for a drop down that is searchable and the example you posted was exactly what I was looking for in that regard. I just didn't know the name of it was "autocomplete". I was looking for a select or drop down.

Comment: Have you tried `<MudGrid Class="justify-center">`

Answer (score 1):

In the other example in the MudBlazor documentation: ['Form using fluent validation'](https://www.mudblazor.com/components/form#using-fluent-validation)

You will find how MudCardContent and MudTable are used both within one form which makes it standout a bit as a form and with the table bit it shows how you can also split it into sections in case you have a bigger form.

You can also combine the grid and the card item and the MudItem where you can add some styling for each field.

My example:

```
<MudCardContent>
    <MudGrid>
        <MudItem md="4">
            <MudTextField @bind-Value="model.Name"
                          Placeholder="Field"
                          For="@(() => model.Name)"
                          Immediate="true"
                          Label="Field Label" />
        </MudItem>
    </MudGrid>
</MudCardContent>
```

Or see the example from the website:
[image: MudBlazor Form Fluent Validation]